# Adding a ground strap from radiator to chassis

Tags: coolant, voltage

Does adding a ground strap from radiator to chassis reduce coolant voltage to almost zero?
I have seen most cars have between 0.1 to 0.2 Volt of coolant voltage. I want to test it by adding a strap to the chassis and see whether the voltage changes in digital multimeter screen or not. Do you have a similar experience?
Most manufacturers isolate radiator from the chassis with some rubber mounts to stop vibrations and I think this increases coolant voltage.
Please bear in mind that I'm talking about a healthy system (All negative grounds of electrical accessories are ok and coolant is not very old).

Comment: That reading is most likely from the (cheap) meter...

Comment: The coolant is very much in contact with ground due to being present in the engine which is grounded.  I really doubt that grounding the radiator will make any different. Why is this a concern anyway?

Comment: @jwh20 - Because the ideal voltage is always zero. Therefore, the closer to zero, the better. Imagine, the voltage dropped a little by adding a ground strap. Then, do you leave the extra ground strap there?

Comment: I suspect it is the corrosion potential/emf, between the aluminum block and the coolant liquid. Not likely high enough to oxidize the Al . You might get a difference by adding corrosion inhibitor to the coolant ( Coolants are blended with some inhibiter as sold , but it may be depleted.).

Comment: Ideal voltage is NOT zero . Ideal protection protection voltage for steel in soil is more negative than  -0.85 V.

Comment: The "electrode potential" voltage between copper and aluminum is about 0.8V, and between copper and iron is about 2.0V. There is nothing surprising about measuring "random" voltages smaller than those figures between the coolant and ground.

Comment: Can you explain how you are measuring the voltage?

Comment: @blacksmith37 - My block and cylinder head are both made of aluminum. It is said that Anything above 0.1 volt is considered corrosive electrolysis for aluminum.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I connect negative probe to negative terminal of the battery and dip positive probe into coolant (without touching radiator). I also do it another way by connecting negative probe to chassis ground connection and dip positive probe into coolant. I have done this test on several cars and most have been above 0.1 Volt.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - What is the ideal voltage for an engine with aluminum head and aluminum block (+ copper radiator)?

Comment: @blacksmith37 - My coolant contain corrosion inhibitors itself. It is an organic-acid  long life coolant (OAT). It is 4 years old now.

Comment: By putting your probe into the coolant you are just making a cell, and therefore seeing a voltage, it doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: If you add a strap to the radiator, you would then be completing an electrical circuit that could cause an increased electrolytic reaction that could eat your radiator or some other components.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I read about this method anywhere. This is probably the most common method of measuring a coolant voltage.

Comment: Add a link to where you read it.

Comment: @HandyHowie - This is just one source out of many sources: https://www.motorweek.org/features/goss_garage/coolant-check

Comment: It says: you need a simple volt meter – you set it on DC volts – you connect the negative cable to the negative terminal of the battery; then with the radiator cap off and the car running at about 2,000 RPM, you dip the red probe into the coolant, like so, and you get a reading on here.

Comment: I have found sites suggesting this.  They are talking about the the coolant becoming an electrolyte as it ages.  Adding a ground strap to the radiator could make the situation worse.  Best just change the coolant.